# Find any employees who earn less than the employee hired immediately after them

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

Can I write MySQL query to identify employees who earn less than employees hired after them.

employees:

```
+--------+----------+----------+------+-------------+------+
| emp_id | emp_name |   job    | mgr  |  hire_date  | sal  |
+--------+----------+----------+------+-------------+------+
|   7369 | Smith    | Clerk    | 7902 | 17-Dec-2010 | 1800 |
|   7499 | Allen    | Salesman | 7698 | 20-Feb-2011 | 2600 |
|   7521 | Ward     | Salesman | 7698 | 22-Feb-2011 | 2250 |
|   7566 | Jones    | Manager  | 7839 | 02-Apr-2011 | 3975 |
|   7654 | Martin   | Salesman | 7698 | 28-Sep-2011 | 2250 |
|   7698 | Blake    | Manager  | 7839 | 01-May-2011 | 3850 |
|   7782 | Clark    | Manager  | 7839 | 09-Jun-2011 | 3450 |
|   7788 | Scott    | Analyst  | 7566 | 09-Dec-2012 | 4000 |
|   7839 | King     | CEO      |      | 12-Nov-2011 | 6000 |
|   7844 | Turner   | Salesman | 7698 | 08-Sep-2011 | 2500 |
|   7876 | Adams    | Clerk    | 7788 | 12-Jan-2013 | 2100 |
|   7900 | James    | Clerk    | 7698 | 03-Dec-2011 | 1950 |
|   7902 | Ford     | Analyst  | 7566 | 03-Dec-2011 | 4000 |
|   7934 | Miller   | Clerk    | 7782 | 23-Jan-2012 | 2300 |
+--------+----------+----------+------+-------------+------+
```

Expected output

```
+--------+----------+----------+------+-------------+
| emp_id | emp_name |   job    |  hire_date  | sal  |
+--------+----------+----------+------+-------------+
|   7369 | Smith    | Clerk    | 17-Dec-2010 | 1800 |
|   7521 | Ward     | Salesman | 22-Feb-2011 | 2250 |
|   7654 | Martin   | Salesman | 28-Sep-2011 | 2250 |
|   7782 | Clark    | Manager  | 09-Jun-2011 | 3450 |
|   7788 | Scott    | Analyst  | 09-Dec-2012 | 4000 |
|   7839 | King     | CEO      | 12-Nov-2011 | 6000 |
|   7900 | James    | Clerk    | 03-Dec-2011 | 1950 |
+--------+----------+----------+------+-------------+
```

should return data in the format:

```
{
    employeeId: xxx,
    employeeName: xxx,
    salary: xxx,
    hireDate: xxx
}
```

Comment: given the sample data, what is the expected/desired result? do you need to group the results (eg, by `job`, by `mgr`)?  what query(s) have you tried so far?

Comment: how did you expect to get the result, one column?

Comment: Hi guys, need output in rows for employees who are earning less. With above table, 7369 and 7521 should occur in output same as above format since employees joined after them earning more.

Comment: Why should `7788 | Scott    | Analyst  | 7566 | 09-Dec-2012 | 4000` be returned? I don't see anyone hired after that and getting more money.

Comment: this is the expected output for which employee_id?

Comment: do you expect a column using a json format?

Comment: yes, json format is expected and about emp_id 7788 , I am sorry my mistake.It should not be returned

Comment: I suggest you put your data in order. That may help you find and tell us what you want. The question is not clear now. Also clarify what that "immediately" means in the title.

Comment: If two employees were hired on the same day (e.g., 7900 and 7902), are both compared against the next most recently hired employee (7839), or is one compared against the other? If the latter, then which is compared against 7839, and which is compared against the one compared to 7839?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a correlated subquery and GROUP_CONCAT() function to get the previous id.

```
select   x.emp_id,
         x.emp_name, 
         x.job,
         x.mgr,
         x.hire_date,
         x.sal,
         (select   group_concat(y.emp_id)
          from     employees y
          where    y.hire_date < x.hire_date
          and      y.sal < x.sal
          order by y.hire_date desc) prev_emp_id
from     employees x
order by x.emp_id;
```

Rextester [here](http://rextester.com/QIU53086)

```
|    | emp_id | emp_name | job      | mgr  | hire_date  | sal  | prev_emp_id                                       |
|:--:|:------:|:--------:|----------|------|------------|------|---------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | 7369   | Smith    | Clerk    | 7902 | 17.12.2010 | 1800 | NULL                                              |
| 2  | 7499   | Allen    | Salesman | 7698 | 20.02.2011 | 2600 | 7369                                              |
| 3  | 7521   | Ward     | Salesman | 7698 | 22.02.2011 | 2250 | 7369                                              |
| 4  | 7566   | Jones    | Manager  | 7839 | 02.04.2011 | 3975 | 7369,7499,7521                                    |
| 5  | 7654   | Martin   | Salesman | 7698 | 28.09.2011 | 2250 | 7369                                              |
| 6  | 7698   | Blake    | Manager  | 7839 | 01.05.2011 | 3850 | 7369,7499,7521                                    |
| 7  | 7782   | Clark    | Manager  | 7839 | 09.06.2011 | 3450 | 7369,7499,7521                                    |
| 8  | 7788   | Scott    | Analyst  | 7566 | 09.12.2012 | 4000 | 7369,7499,7521,7566,7654,7698,7782,7844,7900,7934 |
| 9  | 7839   | King     | CEO      | 0    | 12.11.2011 | 6000 | 7369,7499,7521,7566,7654,7698,7782,7844           |
| 10 | 7844   | Turner   | Salesman | 7698 | 08.08.2011 | 2500 | 7369,7521                                         |
| 11 | 7876   | Adams    | Clerk    | 7788 | 12.01.2013 | 2100 | 7369,7900                                         |
| 12 | 7900   | James    | Clerk    | 7698 | 03.12.2011 | 1950 | 7369                                              |
| 13 | 7902   | Ford     | Analyst  | 7566 | 03.12.2011 | 4000 | 7369,7499,7521,7566,7654,7698,7782,7844           |
| 14 | 7934   | Miller   | Clerk    | 7782 | 23.01.2012 | 2300 | 7369,7521,7654,7900                               |
```

Comment: Hey thanks but,need output in rows for employees who are earning less. With above table, 7369 and 7521 should occur in output same as above format since employees joined after them earning more

Comment: Please add one example of the desired result.

Comment: Hi, updated the question. please have a look